# Python3 tkinter error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

boa noite,
A ideia deste codigo é inserir uma imagem numa interface gráfica 
porem esta sempre a dar o erro e diz que não consegue abrir a imagem

Alguem sabe pk isso esta a acontecer?

este é o meu código

```
class janela:
   def __init__(self,master=None): #master refere se ha janela principal
     #criaçao do conteiner pai
     self.frame=Frame(master)
     self.frame.pack()
     self.photo=PhotoImage(file='imagem.png')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
janela(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece porque não há atribuição para o atributo `photo` da classe `janela`, ele simplesmente é chamado a primeira vez em `self.photo(file='imagem.png')`.

Para adicionar uma imagem com `tkinter`, um dos modos possíveis é:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

class janela:
   def __init__(self,master=None): #master refere se ha janela principal
     #criaçao do conteiner pai
     self.frame=Frame(master)
     self.frame.pack()
     photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imagem.png"))
     self.label = Label(image=photo)
     self.label.photo = photo  # necessário para manter referência
     self.label.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x600')
    janela(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comentários sobre a solução:

- Utilizar a **PIL (Python Imaging Library)** para trabalhar com uma imagem em formato `.png` e salvar isso em uma variável `photo`;
- Colocar essa variável `photo` em algum componente, aqui optou-se por uma label;
- Salvar uma referência extra da imagem;
- E por fim, não acredito que seja a solução mais bonita, mas alcança o objetivo de apresentar uma imagem :)

Para mais informações, inclusive do porque é necessário manter referência para a imagem, recomendo a [leitura](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).